# How to launch chrome driver on any remote machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a requirement where i need to launch the chrome browser on a remote machine. I have explored selenium grid but it requires some static configuration on the remote machine. In my case the remote machine vary and the IP is taken from a properties file hence it is not possible to create all those machines as hub.

Could anyone help me with a more generic way by which i can dynamically launch the chrome driver on the machine for which i read the IP from properties file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If I understood right, you want to start and stop,m maybe even install, ChromeDriver upon request given the device IP address. You could try using SSH to provision ChromeDriver in the machines and start and stop it, although it won't be an easy task. Using a Docker selenium container might be another option.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 :

Check with the team provisioned IP address for the machine. It is possible that IP you are using is public IP (public IP address may change when machine is restarted) . Team can provide you with a private IP(it remains static) and a VPN to access the machine. If you are able to access the machine using this solution , setup selenium grid ,and you will be able to run your tests

Option 2 :

If you get a new machine for every run, request the machine with docker enabled, so you can spin up a selenium grid infrastructure using docker and run your tests there